# SFTP trigger not working

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an SFTP trigger that isn't triggering. I added a file to the SFTP folder and nothing happens. I think I had done this successfully in the past.  I have it set to to check every 5 minutes.

The "trigger history" has status "skipped" for all times.

The Diagnostic Logs is empty. I would assume there would be an entry related to its checking of the SFTP server.

How to go about diagnosing?

Edit: I found that if I clicked on the "skipped" entry that I could see the input and output links

output is

```
{
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Retry-After": "15",
        "x-ms-request-id": "408c1686-fc55-4006-90b2-2a315be6b087",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Date": "Sat, 10 Dec 2016 21:29:18 GMT",
        "Location": "https://logic-apis-eastus.azure-apim.net/apim/sftp/7abdeb1a471c4819ab90548dce96a210/datasets/default/triggers/onupdatedfile?folderId=L3VwdG9kYXRl&triggerstate=eyJGaWxlSWQiOiIiLCJTdGF0dXMiOjEsIldpbmRvd1N0YXJ0VGltZSI6IjAwMDEtMDEtMDFUMDA6MDA6MDAiLCJXaW5kb3dFbmRUaW1lIjoiMDAwMS0wMS0wMVQwMDowMDowMCIsIkxhc3RDb25mbGljdFRpbWUiOiIwMDAxLTAxLTAxVDAwOjAwOjAwIn0%3d",
        "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=008df0d064987de2b42b3cfb32a3b1590a97ba6912e4e96acac4a3385109c610;Path=/;Domain=127.0.0.1",
        "Server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Length": "0",
        "Expires": "-1"
    }
}
```

Looking up "202" I find description as "Command not implemented, superfluous at this site."

How can I diagnose this?

Another edit: I tried with a different SFTP server, and I still get status code 202.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading a comment in another thread, I decided to try creating a new API Connection, and then using that connection in my Logic App. Now the trigger is catching new files.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by disabling the "Preserve Timestamp" option of the SFTP client being used to upload the files. I was using WinSCP, but other SFTP clients have the same feature. This feature changes the timestamp of the uploaded file on the server to match that of the original local file, "preserving" it. Otherwise the timestamp will be the time of upload. Read more [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom#common).

If the Logic App is checking for new files every 5 minutes, and you upload a file created/modified more than 5 minutes ago with timestamp preservation, the Logic App will skip over the file as it thinks its old. Disable the feature in the client being used to upload files, so that the timestamp of the file on the server will be its time of upload. The Logic App will know it's new and fire the trigger.

Microsoft has [specific documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp#how-ftp-triggers-work) about the issue as well.